# Get a random wikipedia article with some conditions/limitations using the API

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

So the [Random Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random) feature of Wikipedia gives a random article, I can also use `RandomInCategory` and specify categories I want, which is what I need.

Now I want to get all the text inside the articles giving some conditions/limitations:

- Only get the text of the article, no images/link/tables etc...
- Ignore some sections (References, Notable people, etc...)
- The article should be available in English (which is already met by the namespace) AND another language, e.g. French.
- Ability to specify a category/categories.

I thought about using a HTML parser in order to do this, maybe work with the Ids/Classes/Headers but I'm not sure this would be 100% accurate.
**Can Wikipedia's API do this somehow?**

Thank you!

---

I found this https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&generator=random&grnnamespace=0&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&grnlimit=10 in another SO question and its interesting, could a category condition be added here and the ability to also get the languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Special:RandomInCategory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:RandomInCategory) (no API equivalent). Note that it's not really random (not a uniform distribution). Other than that (and namespace) there is no way to add further conditions.

Comment: If it's not random then what is it?

Comment: The method is [explained here](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki/blob/a5853433dad7a1aba91940cd6ac79480008671ee/includes/specials/SpecialRandomInCategory.php#L38-L45).

Comment: Okay thanks, I ended up writing a scraper on the random urls.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Petscan](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/PetScan/en) to get lists of articles in any particular category (or combinations). I'm not sure of any functionality for checking that other language articles exist automatically, but I presume there are some tools at Wikidata that can help you. You should be able to pass pageids across and get a list of other languages. As for the actual data collection, I'd recommend using the Python library, [Beautiful Soup](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/).